# Error when calling the next() method in passport.authenticate('local')

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I have some middleware which uses passport.js, which aims to authenticate a user, then move onto the next piece of middleware:

```
exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    console.log('You are authenticated!!')
    next()
  })(req, res, next)
}
```

When the user registers, I see `You are authenticated!!` in my console. So by this logic, the user should be attached to the `req`. So I call `next` and it moves onto this piece of middleware (I want to do something else before the user is redirected):

```
exports.createMatch = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user._id)
}
```

However, an error on my console and webpage shows `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`. Why is this and how do I rectify it?

routes.js:

```
router.post(
  '/register',
  userController.validateRegistration, // validate them
  userController.register, // register them to the db
  authController.authenticate, // authenticate them
  catchErrors(dataController.createMatch) // do some other bits then redirect
)
```

Fairly new to Express. If more code is needed let me know. Apologies if something similar was answered elsewhere.

Regards,
James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line in the source where `req.user` gets set:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/821a474342b1ae900849911b5c3d3ccc4ef5ab86/lib/http/request.js#L44

It's in the method `req.login`. The documentation is here:

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login

It states:

> When the login operation completes, `user` will be assigned to `req.user`.

Further it says:

> `passport.authenticate()` middleware invokes `req.login()` automatically.

So far everything sounds like it should work...

However, if you read the section about providing a **Custom Callback**, which is what you're doing, it states:

> Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling `req.login()`) and send a response.

There are several ways to fix it. You could get rid of the custom callback, you could call `login` inside the callback, or you could just set `req.user = user` yourself.